# Receive telmetry from IoT hub on Android with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-iot-hub

I have a Xamarin.Forms shared project created for Android 7.0 and UWP.

What I am attempting to do is receive information from an IoT hub on Azure.

I have previously been able to receive telemetry to a console application by following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted

I was using **Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging** library

Is this not supported on Android? and if so, is there a way to receive messages  on an android device from an IoT hub using Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the newer library for event Hub monitoring: https://github.com/azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet

This new lib is .Net Standard 1.3 compatible and should work on Xamarin.Android.

We need to update the Azure IoT Hub docs to point to this new lib instead of the older Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging one. I'll make sure it's added to our backlog.